# Getting file that is launching exe

Tags: c#, file

I have been looking around for the solution to my problem, and found nothing. How do you get the file that is being opened up by the default program that you set it to open up with? For example: if I have a file called `HelloWorld.hello`, and I set it up so that a program called `Hello.exe` will open when the file is clicked. How do I get the file that is launching `Hello.exe`?

Comment: What do you mean by "the file that is launching Hello.exe"?  Do you mean to ask how to get the file that has been *passed to* Hello.exe?

Comment: I think so. How would one do that?

Comment: `System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`

Comment: What you're asking is not really clear. Do you mean how do you get a file that is one of your parameters to the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that calls to "execute `HelloWorld.exe`" go through a common methodology programmed into the OS - it's by definition an OS function to handdle execution requests. Thus, the most you'll ever get is your kernal for "what launched me?"

**EDIT** If you want to get the program that is executing current code, ie the entry point of an application, this is accessible via `Environment.CommandLine`. Unless you're building a library accessed by multiple executables, this is not very useful, and if you are, there are few cases where the library *should* know what's calling it.

If you have control of the calling function, you may want to consider passing in some arguments during startup into the targeted program - these are accessible via the `string[]` parameter in `Main`

**EDIT** Elaborating on the option to pass information into `Main`, you can actually have one of several signatures for your `Main` method. Using the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

Will take any command line arguments and pass them into the `args` array. Thus, if you called your program `HelloWorld.exe` (in windows) as

```
HelloWorld "alpha beta" delta gamma
```

then `args` will contains `["alpha beta", "delta", "gamma"]` values. Thus, passing in flags or enabling command line arguments becomes possible

Comment: How do you pass them into the string[] parameter in the Main method?